# Save win32com Outlook attachment directly to variable

Tags: python, pandas, outlook

Fairly new to Python (using 3.6) and am wondering if it is possible to save an Outlook email attachment (csv file) directly to a pandas dataframe. I'm trying to avoid an interim step of saving to file, then using pandas.read_csv to bring the file contents into Python environment.

I'm curious if something like the "open attachment" feature in Outlook can be used to open and assign to variable.

What I have so far (which works)...

```
import pandas
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi=outlook.GetNamespace["MAPI"]
datafldr=mapi.Folders['Main'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Data']
messages=datafldr.Items
num_msgs=messages.count
curr_email=messages[num_msgs-1]
attachments=curr_email.Attachments
curr_att=attachments.Item(1)
```

Is it possible to take the "curr_att" win32 object(?) directly to a pandas dataframe?

Or do I have to continue with...

```
curr_att.SaveAsFile('enterpathhere\datafile.csv')
mydata=pandas.read_csv('enterpathhere\datafile.csv')
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to find a way to do this as well to no avail. I believe the functions available are limited to what is [documented for the Outlook Attachment object type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment).

Unfortunately, it appears that the only option is SaveAsFile

Comment: Your answer seems to have enough info to be a proper answer. Please check the guide [answer] when in doubt